# External URL Re-Direct

Tags: redirect

We have a survey which is based on Microsoft Forms, we are using 3 URLs from our website which all auto re-direct users to the Form. However, I want to check that Google Analytics will pick up user and page views stats so we can monitor performance of the 3 URLS. Can you confirm if there is anything I need to do within Google Analytics to ensure this? I've seen Tag Manager mentioned and Thanks, Jayne